# Math mode: square bracket strange behaviour

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, alignment, brackets

Can you see as the content is not aligned with square brackets?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[ \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\mathrm{L}^3}{\mathrm{t}}} \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Content should be displayed higher. Maybe a `\dfrac` bug? Or maybe I should fine an alternatice to `\left[` and `\right]`?

Comment: That's expected: the brackets are centered around the formula axis, which in this case is the line of the outer fraction, and have the same size above and below this axis. It would be much clearer to type `\left[\frac{1}{\mathrm{L}^3\mathrm{t}^{-1}}\right]` anyway. Or, directly, `[\mathrm{L}^{-3}\mathrm{t}]`

Comment: This is expected behaviour, as the brackets are aligned around the *math axis*. I'd just use `\left[ \frac{1}{\mathrm{L}^3/\mathrm{t}} \right]`. Much more readable.

Comment: @campa You used a slash. Added value, so I think your comment could stand.

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior: the brackets are symmetric with respect to the formula axis, which is the imaginary line where the main fraction line sits on.

I guess that this is some step during dimensional analysis; suppose you follow the [advice by Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652317/4427), but put it in context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\mathrm{L}^3}{\mathrm{t}}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[\frac{\mathrm{t}}{\mathrm{L}^3}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your readers will have a very hard time in interpreting the meaning of such a formula. Which one is the main fraction line? The top one is just slightly longer than the (secondary) bottom one and L<sup>3</sup> lies almost exactly at the same level as the fraction line in the right-hand side.

Take into account that mistaking the main fraction line would lead to very wrong interpretation.

Making the main fraction line longer doesn't really solve the problem:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\;\;1\;\;}{\dfrac{\mathrm{L}^3}{\mathrm{t}}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[\frac{\mathrm{t}}{\mathrm{L}^3}\right]
\]
```

would produce

[image]

which is as unreadable.

Solution: use exponents, as is commonly done in dimensional analysis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[\frac{1}{\mathrm{L}^3\mathrm{t}^{-1}}\right]
=
[\mathrm{L}^{-3}\mathrm{t}]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You obtain a better looking formula with `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\mathrm{L}^3}{\mathrm{t}}} \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]